# Valgrind reports an Invalid Read in __intel_new_memcpy

Tags: c++, oracle, valgrind, oracle-call-interface

Valgrind tool which is a well known memory analyzing tool reports an Invalid Read in OCIStmtPrepare in Oracle C API Function. This can be observed in several such Oracle C API functions.

Please refer the following stack trace.

According to my observations and understanding the the application creates a buffer of 317 bytes. However when it is passed to Oracle library it does some memory copy using the __intel_new_memcpy function. However the __intel_new_memcpy function copies 320 bytes (which is 8 from 312). The actual allocated memory was 317 bytes.

Could you please confirm whether this behaviour correct? What goes wrong in this?

```
==22195== Invalid read of size 8
==22195== at 0x68CD2D9: __intel_new_memcpy (in /x02/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==22195== by 0x5D84158: kpurclientparse (in /x02/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==22195== by 0x5D878DE: kpureq (in /x02/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==22195== by 0x5D607FA: OCIStmtPrepare (in /x02/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==22195== by 0x4099E0: DBCursor::Parse(char const*) (OCICPP.C:1020)
==22195== by 0x40CE29: DBCon::NewCursor(char const*, int) (OCICPP.C:753)
==22195== by 0x4047A6: main (main.cpp:59)
==22195== Address 0xa2e7e68 is 312 bytes inside a block of size 317 alloc'd
==22195== at 0x4C26E1C: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==22195== by 0x4EBD00F: String::Set(char const*, unsigned int) (String.cpp:544)
==22195== by 0x4EBD169: String::Set(char const*) (String.cpp:512)
==22195== by 0x4EBD188: String::operator=(char const*) (String.cpp:590)
==22195== by 0x404784: main (main.cpp:55)
```

Comment: Post the main.cpp file please (at least up to line 60).

Comment: This might be a fake alarm. OCI generates quite a lot of them, because it was compiled using using Intel's ICC.